# VBA - adding a sheet with duplicates and tranposing output into rows

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, transpose

I have the following data set, which contains duplicates.

```
values:
2880CR-20.36KX53305DECOAK2015
F05572-CN48517OCTOAK2016
F05572-CN48517DECOAK2016
F05572-CN48517NOVOAK2015
F05572-CN48517NOVOAK2015(duplicate)
F05572-CN48517DECOAK2015
F05573-CN48517JANOAK2016
F05573-CN48517FEBOAK2016
F05573-CN48517JANOAK2015
F05573-CN48517FEBOAK2015
F05573-CN48517MAROAK2015
F05573-CN48517APROAK2015
F05573-CN48517APROAK2015(duplicate)
```

I am trying to create a macro that will look at the values in column A, from A2:A (count of rows in column), and return a list of the duplicate values contained in the string declared "strMyDupList". Basically, if there is atleast 1 duplicate, the msgbox will pop up and the new sheet created with the columns address and values and I am trying to list out all the values seperated my a comma VERTICALLY, instead of horizontally across the sheet. so like:

```
Address     value
$A$5        F05572-CN48517NOVOAK2015
$A$13       F05573-CN48517APROAK2015
```

my code is :

```
If strMyDupList <> "" Then
    MsgBox "The following entries have been used more than once:" & vbNewLine & strMyDupList

    Worksheets.Add.name = name
    Worksheets(name).Range("A1").Value = "Location"
    Worksheets(name).Range("B1").Value = "Value"
'    Worksheets(name).Range("A2:C2").Value = Split(strMyDupList, ",")
    Worksheets(name).Range("B4:B6") = Split(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strMyDupList), ",")
```

The results are that I am able to get the values tranposed from horizontal to vertical, however, with this code, it is only returning the FIRST VALUE in the list of values in the string, so it's returning:

```
Address     value
$A$5        F05572-CN48517NOVOAK2015
$A$5        F05572-CN48517NOVOAK2015 (should be F05573-CN48517APROAK2015)
```

I've seen the `UBound` with `Resize` could work but I have no idea how the syntax works or is used. Can someone assist?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example of how to leave duplicates out of your information.

Essentially, it sorts all of your information. Therefore, when you sort you'll get the consecutive value which would be itself if it was a dupe.

It uses a .NET feature, `System.Collections.ArrayList`, that was in 2.0 & 3.5 so that has to be installed on your machine. Usually it already is but it may not be. You can turn it on through `Programs & Features`.

```
Sub StringArrayDupeChecker()
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim holder As String
    Dim strMyList() As String
    Dim myDupeData As Variant
    Dim str As String

    str = "one,two,three,three,three,four,five,five"
    strMyList = Split(str, ",")

    holder = ""
    Set var = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set myDupeData = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    For Each i In strMyList
        var.Add (i)
    Next i

    var.Sort

    For Each j In var
        If Not j = holder Then
            'do your stuff
            str = "notDupe"
        Else
            myDupeData.Add(j)
        End If
        holder = j
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I'm not trying to leave duplicates out of the data. Rather, I'm trying to identify the duplicates, so I can cross-reference with the other data set as to why. With this macro, it should make it easier.

Comment: Of course, see my updated code. A simple change. ArrayList is very powerful, weird how they deprecated it. I would recommend also maybe moving to add-ins with c# where you have access to Lists and Linq and this would've been a lot simpler. Though I understand moving your entire code-base and training devs is an entirely different issue.